# How do I count the number of vector points that occur within a specific raster value?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I am working with NLCD Raster data and Point Vector data. I want to calculate the number of points that occur within certain raster values of the NLCD data set. I tried the Raster to Polygon with the hope I could do a Clip or Intersect but I am not getting a return value.

[image]

I am working with some NLCD data and am trying to count

Answer (score 3):

Tip the problem on its head, you could use [Extract Values to Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-values-to-points.htm) tool to pass the pixel value to the point. Then simply use the [summary statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) and set the case parameter to be your pixel value that has been transferred to the point dataset and count on objectID/FID.